# Unsupported SDK version: our app builders do not support SDK version 45, yet. The latest SDK version is 45.0.0

Tags: react-native

Unsupported SDK version
Error: Unsupported SDK version
at Object.checkIfSdkIsSupported (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/utils.ts:80:11)
at AndroidBuilder.checkProjectConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/AndroidBuilder.ts:50:5)
at AndroidBuilder.prepareProjectInfo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:72:5)
at AndroidBuilder.command (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/build/BaseBuilder.ts:41:7)

Answer (score 1):

You need to build using `eas-cli`

```
npm install -g eas-cli
eas build -p android
```

Comment: https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/#4-run-a-build

Answer (score 0):

expo 5.4.6
eas-cli/0.52.0 win32-x64 node-v16.13.0
sdk 45

I managed to create an apk (not aab) for my project using this command:

```
eas build --profile preview
```

This method is described here:
https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/